# How can I find out if the superclass also implements the same method that my subclass implements?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to know if the superclass implements method A from my subclass, which also implements method A, so that I can safely call [super A] from my subclass without getting an exception.

NSObject's respondsToSelector: doesn't work in this case, since that will always return true (because my subclass implements the method in question). Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the class method `instancesRespondToSelector:` to do this. So from the subclass you can call `[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(...)]` to determine if the superclass implements the method you require.

Comment: What is equivalent for class methods? say, i want to test if a class level selector is in it super class or in subclass?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(...)]` will not work, if the class that implements it is subclassed and the method is called on the instance of the subclassed-class.
One solution is to explicitly type the name of the current class that implements it:

```
[[ExplicitClassName superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(...)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [[[self class] superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(. )]]]

[super respondsToSelector:] invokes the superclass's implementation of respondsToSelector, which is likely the same as the current class's. It does *not* check if the superclass implements the method.